Is this a legitimate method of finding another prime number?
My motivation for asking this question stems from Euclid's elegantly simple proof of the infinitude of prime numbers.  I am not  suggesting an alternative proof, since my method, even if is valid, requires assumption of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which Euclid's proof does not require.  I just thought that this was a fun way of finding an additional prime number. 
Given a set S of prime numbers, find an additional one as follows.  Express S as the union of two non-overlapping subsets P and Q. Let m equal the product of the members of P and n equal the product of the members of Q.  Then m+n is a number that is not divisible by a number in S.
Proof: For m+n to be divisible by a number in S, it must be divisible by some number in P or Q. It can't be divisible by some value p in P, since m is divisible by p but n is not. Similarly, m+n is not divisible by a number in Q. Therefore m+n is not divisible by a number in P or Q and therefore not by a number in S.

Yep that works and doesn’t use anything fancy (all you need is that $p|ab$ implies $p|a$ or $p|b$)

What if the set S consists of the primes 3 and 5?  8 is relatively prime to the members of S, but not prime.

@AndyWalls I think the assumption is that we get the next prime number by taking some prime factor of $m+n$. In your case we get $3+5 = 8$ and then the prime $2 | 8$ is indeed a new prime not in $S$.

Example : $S={2,3,5,7}, P={2,3}, Q={5,7}, m=2.3=6, n=5.7=35, m+n=41$. Moreover, $41<7^2$ so $41$ is prime

Note that your proof actually becomes Euclid's proof in the case $Q = \emptyset$, taking the empty product to be $1$.

$m+n$ is a number not divisible by a number in $S$, but may still be composite. For example in the question using $Q=\emptyset$: Is Euclid's proof on the infinitude of primes flawed because it yields some composites?

(+1) for the idea , but there is no question , and this idea is not really new. But you successfully redetected it.

This is Stieltjes’s proof given in 1890.

This variation on Euclid's proof is attributed to Stieltjes (by Ribenboim), cf. here in the linked dupe.
